# É possível montar layout padrão para páginas HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Se tenho duas páginas: `pagina1.html` e `pagina2.html`, que são bem parecidas, é possível usar uma página `layout.html` para determinar elementos comuns de cada página? E assim evitar também a repetição de `tags` como acontece nos projetos Asp.Net MVC, Ruby on Rails, etc...

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67429/23593)

Comment: Eu diria que a melhor maneira de resolver essa situação é recorrendo a templates html. [Neste link](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) você poderá encontrar várias opções de acordo com o que melhor lhe convier.

Answer (score 1):

/////função javascript

```
function url(link){
        document.getElementById("conteudo").setAttribute('src','paginas/'+link);
    }
```

////links HTML

```
<div onclick="url('inicio.html')">Início</div>
<div onclick="url('sobre.html')">Sobre</div>
<div onclick="url('contato.html')">contato</div>
```

///// IFRAME COLOCAR ENTRE O HEADER E O FOOTER DE SEU SITE ONDE APARECERÁ O CONTEÚDO.

```
<iframe id="conteudo">
</iframe>
```

LEMBRANDO QUE AI VOCÊ TERA QUE POR CSS RETIRAR A BORDA DO IFRAME E A BARRA DE ROLLAGEM TAMBÉM SE PREFERIR.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar Angular.js e Angular-route.js,
ficaria assim:

Pagina HTML

```
<html ng-app="TesteApp">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Teste Rotas</title>
   </head>        
   <body>
    <a href="#/pagina-1">Pagina 1</a>
    <a href="#/pagina-2">Pagina 2</a>        
    <h1> Master Page </h1>

    <div ng-view>
      <!--Dentro da div ng-view , será renderizado nossas partials-->
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Arquivo main.js

```
//Modulo do app
var app = angular.module("TesteApp", ['ngRoute']);

 //Configuração das rotas
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider        
      .when("/pagina-1", { //URL
          templateUrl: "caminho/pagina-1.html", //Caminho da pagina HTML
          controller: "nomeController" //controller que será usado
      })
    .when("/pagina-2", { //URL
        templateUrl: "caminho/pafina-2.html", //Caminho da pagina HTML
        controller: "nomeController" //controller que será usado
    })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/pagina-1' }); //Se não for nenhuma url , redireciona para esta
 });

    app.controller("nomeController",function($scope){ //Controller
       $scope.mensagem = "Olá"
 });
```

E ai conforme a URL for mudando , as paginas serão renderizadas dentro da div com ng-view.

Answer (score -1):

Eu geralmente uso uma pagina padrão que chamo de MasterPage.html e nela adiciono meus elementos fixos, e as outras páginas vou chamando via include a maneira que for precisando.

Exemplo tenha a página padrão com meu Header e meu Footer fixo e ao clicar em algum link do meu menu chamo a página referente que contém apenas as informações da página.

Comment: Exato @RodrigoSantos , mas minha dúvida é justamente como fazer isso usando puramente HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

Comment: no caso eu usaria como você quer puramente javascript minha master com os conteúdos que seriam fixos, e na parte do conteúdo que seria dinâmico eu colocaria um iframe, e ai através do javascript você vai alterando o src do iframe.

Comment: Você teria um exemplo pra que eu pudesse entender mais claramente?

Comment: respondi a você ok, o jeito que eu implementei em um código com a mesma situação.